# Nginx ,haproxy configuration

Tags: nginx, haproxy

can you guys please help me with my haproxy and nginx configuration:

On HA proxy my configuration is:
acl demoafc_url hdr_dom(host) -i demoafc.testtest.com
use_backend demoafc if demoafc_url
backend demoafc
server demoafc 192.168.24.121:80

On NGINX (VM with IP 192.168.24.121) my configuration is

[root@afc-core-app-demo conf.d]# cat mst-afc.conf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtOtj.png)

For the first part, if i enter in my browser (localy or remotely) https://demoafc.testtest.com/mst-test/api everything works OK.

For second part, if i enter in browser: https://demoafc.testest.com, my browser then shows url  http://192.168.24.121:8080/. And this works only locally (when connected to VPN, remotely not - link doesn't open).

I would like for second part to be available also on https://demoafc.testest.com, that browser don't show
http://192.168.24.121:8080/

Please help

Comment: Add your nginx config to your question using [syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting). Do not use images to show the code or configuration files content. Do not write an answer to your own question if you want to add something to it - just edit your question instead.

Comment: If i enter IP address localy, without hostname http://192.168.24.121:8080, then my browser redirects me to http://192.168.24.121:8080/#/. So i would like if i enter in browser https://demoafc.testest.com i am  redirected to http://192.168.24.121:8080/#/, and if i enter https://demoafc.testest.com/home i am redirected to http://192.168.24.121:8080/#/home.

Answer (score 1):

enter image description here - click to see picture of nginx configuration

Answer (score 0):

If i enter IP address localy, without hostname http://192.168.24.121:8080, then my browser redirects me to http://192.168.24.121:8080/#/. So i would like if i enter in browser https://demoafc.testest.com i am  redirected to http://192.168.24.121:8080/#/, and if i enter https://demoafc.testest.com/home i am redirected to http://192.168.24.121:8080/#/home.